# How to know what today is, in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make bot that know what day is today, i have example code below but i dont know how to fix this.

```
  client.on("message", msg =>{
  if (msg.content === "!today"){
    If (Today is Sunday){
        msg.reply("Time to Holiday")
      }
    else if(Today is monday){
        msg.reply("Time to work")
      }
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) gives you the current date and time. It has a method [`.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) which gives you the day of the week as a number. Sunday is `0`; Monday is `1`. So:

```
const dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();

if (dayOfWeek === 0) { // is it Sunday?
```

Note that this is the *bot server* date and time. Different users might be on different days, due to time zones.